# XJC scope within XJB binding file

Tags: binding, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I got XJB binding file where I want to replace ALL dates with java.util.Date and I would like one specific element (with name 'MyElementName') to extend my custom class:

```
My XJB file:

<jaxb:bindings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           jaxb:version="2.0">

    <!-- replace JAXBElement with real object where nillable="true" and minOccurs="0" -->
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">

        <!-- replace all dates with java.util.Date -->
        <jaxb:javaType xmlType="xsd:dateTime" name="java.util.Date"
                       parseMethod="cz.i.sdp.nsessapi.util.DataTypeConverter.parseDateTime"
                       printMethod="cz.i.sdp.nsessapi.util.DataTypeConverter.printDateTime"/>
        <jaxb:javaType xmlType="xsd:date" name="java.util.Date"
                       parseMethod="cz.i.sdp.nsessapi.util.DataTypeConverter.parseDateTime"
                       printMethod="cz.i.sdp.nsessapi.util.DataTypeConverter.printDateTime"/>
        <jaxb:javaType xmlType="xsd:time" name="java.util.Date"
                       parseMethod="cz.i.sdp.nsessapi.util.DataTypeConverter.parseDateTime"
                       printMethod="cz.i.sdp.nsessapi.util.DataTypeConverter.printDateTime"/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>

    <!-- Only element with name 'MyElementName' should extend 
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="mySchema.xsd">
      <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='MyElementName']">
        <xjc:superClass name="net.test.Whatever"/>
      </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

The XJC enhancements will be silently ignored unless they are inside `<globalBindings>`. But then all generated classes will extend my custom class and I don't want that.

Is there a way to specify global bindings together with "scoped" bindings?

In [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html) is mentioned "Global Scope", "Schema scope", "Definition Scope" and "Component scope" and they say "pecifically, declarations towards the top of the pyramid inherit and supersede declarations below them".

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I.e. show the XJB file which does not work for you. You can specify `globalBindings` together with simply `bindings`.

Comment: I updated original question with better explanation and complete XJB file.